# Magento 2 Multiple Store View Pricing error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, extensions

i tried to install Multiple Store View Pricing modules and add the files in this path **/var/www/html/app/code/MultiStoreViewPricing** but get the below error after run command php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**Updating modules:
Plugin class Bss\MultiStoreViewPricingTierPrice\Plugin\Product\Collection doesn't exist
In PluginList.php line 182:**

[enter link description here](https://i.ibb.co/j5wr5Sd/2019-09-26-143820.png)

can anyone help me

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

/var/www/html/app/code/**Bss**/MultiStoreViewPricing

you forgot the vendor

Comment: could you please provide me with installation steps 
i have 4 module 
MultiStoreViewPricing
MultiStoreViewPricingCatalogRule
MultiStoreViewPricingPriceIndexer
MultiStoreViewPricingTierPrice